# Cannot upload video with Youtube API using Django (set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS error )

Tags: django, google-api, django-forms, django-views, youtube-api

I'm trying to upload a video to my channel using Youtube API V3. I have setup a developer account and have received the Client ID as well as the Secret Key. However I get the following error when I try to upload a file.

```
Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.
```

I have two apps, **django_youtube** which has the **settings.py** file and the other app is called **core.**

**settings.py (django_youtube/settings.py)** *I have the keys added on my version of the code*

```
import os
from unipath import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
# BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '20p)4xp)osw$26w-b2_vobd0-#!%7pg)t7%02907naw8c_p&pi'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Google Auth

GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = ""
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = ""


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_youtube.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_youtube.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True




# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR.parent.child('staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR.parent.child('uploads')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py (django_youtube/urls.py)**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(('core.urls', 'core'), namespace='core')),
]
```

**models.py (core/models.py)**

```
class CredentialsModel(models.Model):
    credential = CredentialsField()
```

**urls.py (core/urls.py)**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path

from .views import HomePageView, AuthorizeView, Oauth2CallbackView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('authorize/', AuthorizeView.as_view(), name='authorize'),
    path('oauth2callback/', Oauth2CallbackView.as_view(),name='oauth2callback')

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Views.py (core/views.py)**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic.base import View

from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets, OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.contrib import xsrfutil
from oauth2client.contrib.django_util.storage import DjangoORMStorage
from .models import CredentialsModel

from django import forms
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

import tempfile
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

class YouTubeForm(forms.Form):
    video = forms.FileField()


class HomePageView(FormView):
    template_name = 'core/home.html'
    form_class = YouTubeForm

    def form_valid(self, form):

        fname = form.cleaned_data['video'].temporary_file_path()

        storage = DjangoORMStorage(
            CredentialsModel, 'id', self.request.user.id, 'credential')
        credentials = storage.get()

        client = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

        body = {
            'snippet': {
                'title': 'Video',
                'description': 'Test Description',
                'tags': 'django,howto,video,api',
                'categoryId': '27'
            },
            'status': {
                'privacyStatus': 'unlisted'
            }
        }

        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('wb', suffix='yt-django') as tmpfile:
            with open(fname, 'rb') as fileobj:
                tmpfile.write(fileobj.read())
                insert_request = client.videos().insert(
                    part=','.join(body.keys()),
                    body=body,
                    media_body=MediaFileUpload(
                        tmpfile.name, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
                )
                insert_request.execute()

        return HttpResponse('It worked!')

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
            client_id=settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret=settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET,
            scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
            redirect_uri='http://localhost:8000/oauth2callback/')

class AuthorizeView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        storage = DjangoORMStorage(
            CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user.id, 'credential')
        credential = storage.get()


        if credential is None or credential.invalid == True:
            flow.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(
                settings.SECRET_KEY, request.user)
            authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
            return redirect(authorize_url)
        return redirect('/')

class Oauth2CallbackView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not xsrfutil.validate_token(
            settings.SECRET_KEY, request.GET.get('state').encode(),
            request.user):
                return HttpResponseBadRequest()
        credential = flow.step2_exchange(request.GET)
        storage = DjangoORMStorage(
            CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user.id, 'credential')
        storage.put(credential)

        return redirect('/')
```

**Form Template (core/templates/core/home.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Upload your video</h1>
<p>Here is the form:</p>
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**What I've tried**

Upon googling the error, I found that the issue was resolved for a lot of people by setting the environment variable as

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/path/to/file.json"
```

In order to do so, I had to set up a service account, downloaded the credentials json file and created the environment variable. However, my application returned a 401 error and I found out that, service accounts don't work with Youtube API.

Not sure how to proceed from here. Completely stuck. Any sort of help is appreciated!

P.S Do note that the authorization works fine. Running localhost:8000/authorize brings up the google login screen, to grant permission for the app to access youtube.